# Exibir/Esconder uma class - JS

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde, pessoal!

Preciso fazer o seguinte com JavaScript:

Pegar a situação do produto "Disponível" ou "Indisponível" e criar uma condição.

Caso o produto esteja disponível: exibir class de preço.
Caso esteja indisponível: ocultar class de preço.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Obrigado!

Comment: Olá, tudo bom? Seja bem vindo ao SOPT, para podermos te ajudar nos mostre até onde você conseguiu chegar no seu código, quais são suas dificuldades e qual o resultado esperado. Dificilmente você irá conseguir ajuda para fazermos o algoritmo para você e muito provalvemente sua pergunta será fechada caso seja ampla demais. Altere sua pergunta com seus códigos atuais e mais pessoas poderão te ajudar. Abraço!

Comment: Boa tarde Gobatto, bem vindo ao Stackoverflow! Complementando o comentário do Pedro, você pode ler [como criar um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) para ajudar os usuários a entenderem seu problema e possam te ajudar de forma mais efetiva.